# Jmeter double quotes in attributes xml data

Tags: xml, jmeter

i'm using Jmetter for testing server API, which sends data in xml format.
I encountered such a problem that the values ​​of some attributes XML data contain quotation marks, whereby jemeter displays an error message:

```
Assertion failure message: Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message from the JMeter log and the xml text you're sending? This doesn't sound like a JMeter issue per-se.

Comment: Assertion error: false
Assertion failure: true
Assertion failure message: Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: This tells me that all Jmeter

Comment: There is probably an extra character (visible or not visible) before your actual xml content. Can you paste the complete XML content here?

Comment: If you try to send the data without the quotes in the XML data does the script to run correctly?

Comment: [link]http://www.tvzavr.ru/api/tvz/catalog?limit=15
Here is a link that returns XML data. In the description of the attribute can uvidit double quotes

Comment: If I check the data which came in response to a request without the quotes inside attribute values ​​then everything is fine